# Error Printing PDF in Windows 10

Tags: c#, pdf, windows-10, shellexecute

I have an application that prints PDF files using ShellExecute with the "Print" or "PrintTo" verb--similar to the code below:

```
Process p = new Process();
try
{
    p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        UseShellExecute = true,
        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
        Verb = "Print",
        FileName = "c:\\temp\\TestPage.pdf"
    };
    p.Start();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Exception");
}
```

This works fine in Windows 7 with Adobe installed: it opens the PDF file and sends it to the printer. In Windows 10, however, it shows a message with an exception.

> No application is associated with the specified file for this operation

What would be a better way to send a specified PDF file to the printer from my program in any Windows version?

Comment: Well, no, you don't have an application that prints PDF files.  You have one that asks *another* program to print it.  The exception message says that you don't have any such program installed.  That is easy to fix of course.

Comment: maybe you have the "print" option missing...read [this](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/500295)

Comment: If I right-click a PDF file in Explorer on my Windows 10 system, there is no Print option on the menu. Double-clicking the file opens it in Microsoft Edge.

Comment: @Pizzor2000 does your Win 10 machine has any PDF file opening software...like Adobe/Foxit? if you don't...then your code will never work.

Comment: If there is no Print option in the menu, there is no print handler installed, which means you cannot use the verb *Print*. You have basically four  choices: 1) open the file and let the user decide how to print it, 2) require the user to install Acrobat Reader or another PDF reader that adds a print handler, 3) use a PDF library that you can include with your app that allows you to print PDFs directly yourself, or 4) stop using PDFs and do your own printing directly to the printer.

Comment: @KenWhite, I'm currently looking into your option #4--changing the system to print the page from a WPF layout instead of a PDF.